# reference multiple types in json schema array

Tags: jsonschema

I am trying to define an array property of an object in a json schema v7, but validation isn't working. How can I correctly reference multiple type definitions to be used in an array? Here an array for Directory can contain more directories or routes:

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "$id": "RootDirectory",
    "title": "Directory",
    "description": "Build a directory for javascript app routing.",
    "type": "object",
    "definitions": {
        "Route": {
            "type": "object",
            "description": "A simple endpoint declaration.",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
                "path": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "An endpoint without forward slashes.",
                    "examples": ["welcome"],
                    "minLength": 1
                },
                "variableSuffix": {
                    "description": "A string that is appended to the path variable name during build.",
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "required": ["path"]
        },
        "Directory": {
            "type": "object",
            "description": "Contains child directories or routes for recursive tree building.",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
                "path": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "An endpoint without forward slashes.",
                    "examples": ["welcome"],
                    "minLength": 1
                },
                "variableSuffix": {
                    "description": "A string that is appended to the path variable name during build.",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "childNodes": {
                    "minItems": 1,
                    "type": "array",
                    "description": "An array of routes, linkedRoutes, subDirectories, or linkedSubDirectories.",
                    "contains": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "oneOf": [
                            {"$ref": "#/definitions/Route"},
                            {"$ref": "#/definitions/Directory"}
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            "required": ["path", "childNodes"]
        },
    },
    "properties": {
        "directories":{
            "type": "array",
            "contains": {
                "type": "object",
                "allOf": [{"$ref": "#/definitions/Directory"}]
            },
            "minItems": 1
        },
        "rootPath": {
            "type": "string",
            "default": ""
        }
    },
    "required": ["directories"]
}
```

for instance, this is valid and shouldn't be since it contains an object with invalid properties:

```json
{
    "rootPath": "api",
    "directories": [
      {
        "path": "a",
        "childNodes": [
            {
              "path": "a",
              "variableSuffix": "s"
            },
            {
              "invalidProperty" : "a"
            }
         ]
      }
     ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem that the property `/directories/0/childNodes/1/invalidProperty` should not be permitted?  The schema does not state that all the array items in childNodes must be valid -- it only specifies that childNodes must *contain* a valid item, and item #0 does validate, therefore the overall schema validates.

To assert that *all* the items in childNodes must be valid, change `contains` at `/definitions/Directory/properties/childNodes/contains` to `items` -- the `items` keyword specifies a schema that must be validated against *all* array items, whereas `contains` only asserts that at least one array item must validate.